# Unit Tests not Compiling or Being found without mod tests in main.rs. Is this a requirement or am I missing some configuration?

Tags: unit-testing, rust, rust-cargo

In my main RS I have to declare mod tests; in the main.rs file for my unit tests to run. Coming from other languages, my startup file never has had to contain any information about the unit tests. Is this a standard in rust, or is there some configuration I am missing?

My file structure is as such:

```
src/
-- config/
-- models/
-- services/
-- tests/    <-- this is where my mod.rs for my tests are
main.rs
```

When running cargo test with a main including:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests;
```

my unit tests are found, and they run.

If I remove the mod tests in main, running the same cargo test command does not run my unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, cargo only care about `src/main.rs`, so yes you need to tell rust there is a mod call tests.

Cargo have some special file/folders already, there is a `tests` folder but its need to be in the root of the project path.

> Integration tests go in the tests directory. [Package Layout](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/guide/project-layout.html)

Read more:

- [Writing Automated Tests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-00-testing.html)